# What is the best way to change an XML attribute with DOM4J

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I'm trying to alter a value on a XML file with DOM4J. The file is not too big but it has a lot of tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.013">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <parameter key="logverbosity" value="init"/>
    <parameter key="random_seed" value="2001"/>
    <parameter key="send_mail" value="never"/>
    <parameter key="notification_email" value=""/>
    <parameter key="process_duration_for_mail" value="30"/>
    <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_csv" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read CSV" width="90" x="45" y="30">
        <parameter key="csv_file" value="C:\Documents and Settings\Geral\workspace\AdaptDBAnalisysPlatform_Core\Results\QueryResults\P1\Results1.csv"/>
        <parameter key="column_separators" value=","/>
        <parameter key="trim_lines" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="use_quotes" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="quotes_character" value="&quot;"/>
        <parameter key="escape_character" value="\"/>
        <parameter key="skip_comments" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="comment_characters" value="#"/>
        <parameter key="parse_numbers" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="decimal_character" value="."/>
        <parameter key="grouped_digits" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="grouping_character" value=","/>
        <parameter key="date_format" value=""/>
        <parameter key="first_row_as_names" value="false"/>
        <list key="annotations">
          <parameter key="0" value="Name"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="time_zone" value="SYSTEM"/>
        <parameter key="locale" value="English (United States)"/>
        <parameter key="encoding" value="windows-1252"/>
        <list key="data_set_meta_data_information">
          <parameter key="0" value="idUSER.true.integer.id"/>
          <parameter key="1" value="GENERO.true.integer.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="2" value="IDADE.true.binominal.attribute"/>
          <parameter key="3" value="PALAVRACHAVE.true.polynominal.label"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="read_not_matching_values_as_missings" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="datamanagement" value="double_array"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Set Role" width="90" x="45" y="165">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="PALAVRACHAVE"/>
        <parameter key="target_role" value="label"/>
        <list key="set_additional_roles">
          <parameter key="idUSER" value="id"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="k_medoids" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Clustering (2)" width="90" x="246" y="30">
        <parameter key="add_cluster_attribute" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="add_as_label" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="remove_unlabeled" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="k" value="4"/>
        <parameter key="max_runs" value="100"/>
        <parameter key="max_optimization_steps" value="100"/>
        <parameter key="use_local_random_seed" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="local_random_seed" value="1992"/>
        <parameter key="measure_types" value="MixedMeasures"/>
        <parameter key="mixed_measure" value="MixedEuclideanDistance"/>
        <parameter key="nominal_measure" value="DiceSimilarity"/>
        <parameter key="numerical_measure" value="EuclideanDistance"/>
        <parameter key="divergence" value="GeneralizedIDivergence"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_type" value="radial"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_gamma" value="1.0"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_sigma1" value="1.0"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_sigma2" value="0.0"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_sigma3" value="2.0"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_degree" value="3.0"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_shift" value="1.0"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_a" value="1.0"/>
        <parameter key="kernel_b" value="0.0"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="map_clustering_on_labels" compatibility="5.3.013" expanded="true" height="76" name="Map Clustering on Labels" width="90" x="313" y="165"/>
      <connect from_op="Read CSV" from_port="output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="Clustering (2)" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Clustering (2)" from_port="cluster model" to_op="Map Clustering on Labels" to_port="cluster model"/>
      <connect from_op="Clustering (2)" from_port="clustered set" to_op="Map Clustering on Labels" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Map Clustering on Labels" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

The idea is simple. I want to change the value of the line `<parameter key="k" value="4"/>`
  (of k_medoids operator) for another value. Thus i worte the following code http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-dom4j/index.html?ca=drs:

```
   PARAMETERS_Key = document.selectNodes("//operator/parameter/@key" ); //find parameter K
             PARAMETERS_Key_IT = PARAMETERS_Key.iterator();

             while(PARAMETERS_Key_IT.hasNext())
             {
                PARAMETERS_Value = document.selectNodes("//operator/parameter/@value" ); //Value of the parameter
                PARAMETERS_Value_IT = PARAMETERS_Value.iterator();

                Attribute KEY=(Attribute)PARAMETERS_Key_IT.next();
                Attribute VALUE=(Attribute)PARAMETERS_Value_IT.next();

                 if(KEY.getValue().equals("k"))  //if Parameter key is k, then change its value for 4
                     VALUE.setValue("41000"); 
             }

             XMLWriter output = new XMLWriter(new FileWriter( new File("c:/catalog/catalog-modified.xml") ));
             output.write( document );
             output.close();
```

Apparently, the Xpaths are correct: confirmed through http://www.xpathtester.com/test, however i get the following exception, that show that, apparently, the Xpath is not ok:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/JaxenException
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.createXPath(DocumentFactory.java:230)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.createXPath(AbstractNode.java:207)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.selectNodes(AbstractNode.java:164)
    at general.XMLParser.modifyDocument(XMLParser.java:38)
    at dataMinning.processes.P1.<init>(P1.java:15)
    at dataMining.ModelCaller.Model1(ModelCaller.java:22)
    at dataMining.ModelCaller.work(ModelCaller.java:16)
    at general.Begin.main(Begin.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.JaxenException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

I don't see any problem. What am i missing?

Thank in advance

Comment: Just figured it out. Jaxen library was missing. But i still cannot successfully change the file

Comment: I have to admit that I've been ignoring this one because I have a personal bias against DOM4J. It really has no significant advantages over the much more portable W3C DOM, as far as I can tell, so I haven't bothered to learn its quirks. If others feel the same way, you might get more help if you migrated to the standard solution. Just a thought.

Comment: Do you think its better to use W3C DOM? I'm using DOM4J because i searched online and, as far as i can tell seems thats the best solution. But i will certainly have a look ate W3C DOM ;)

Comment: DOM4J apps and skills will take some work to transfer to the standard W3C DOM. The latter, _being_ standard, is implemented far more widely and is more likely to be what you'll have to work with when integrating with other folks' code. My own perception, which may be wrong, is that DOM4J has passed its time if it ever had one. JAXP (including DOM and SAX and TrAX) remains a stronger community, and StAX seems to have a lot of traction. Of course this may vary by community, but that also seems to be what I'm seeing here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is much more easy to solve using W3C DOM as keshlam suggested.
Here's my solution to update the value 4 to another value in the line `<parameter key="k" value="4"/>`

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;*/


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;



import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;



import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;




public class XMLParser {


     public void modifyDocument(String inputXml)
     {


                 try {
                     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(inputXml));

                     DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                     DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                     Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

                     XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

                     String expression = "//operator[@class='k_medoids']/parameter[@key='k']";
                     String email = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);

                     NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

                     System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
                     for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                         NamedNodeMap attr = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes();
                        Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("value");
                        nodeAttr.setTextContent("VALUE TO CHANGE"); 
                     }

                  // write the content into xml file
                        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
                        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(inputXml));
                        transformer.transform(source, result);              

                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (SAXException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TransformerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
             }

}
```

I must say that XPath is very useful.

Best Regards